# CSS to change hover color on WooCommerce add to cart

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

WordPress/WooCommerce question: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo68t.png)Anyone have good CSS for changing the hover color behind an Add to Cart field? (See pics--cursor hover changes one field's background to grey.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the code on your website, generally the process is:

1. Target the element that you want to change the color for
2. Set a new color on hover

You'll need to find the class or ID that's being used on the element that surrounds your Add to Cart button. You can do that by right-clicking on it, and choosing Inspect.

Your CSS will look something like:

```
.class:hover {
  background-color: #333; /* whatever color you want */
}
```

Here's more on the CSS hover selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp